# How to dynamically load & render react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to be able to dynamically include react components into my project, because I want to setup a plugin system and not every user has the same plugins/components enabled. Also they are/might get too big to submit all of them to every user. I tried to find out how to do that, but it seems that React might not support that use-case.

**TLDR**: How do I load React components from server when needed? Do I have to switch to Angular because react has no templateUrl equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React components are defined in JavaScript files, so you can load components in just as you’d load in any other JavaScript file. If you’re not using any sort of module mechanism like RequireJS, that might be as simple as injecting a `script` tag into the document. If you’re using something like RequireJS, you would just tell the loader that you want an extra module loaded.

Comment: I will try that when I need to implement that part, but it sounds like it should work. I accept the answer for now, but will have to unaccept in case it doesn't work.